# Passing argument to javascript function from primeface remotecommand function

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I tried to pass a parameter from primeface remote command to javascript like this:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="validateFormNumber" process="@this"
    update="FormNumberValidation @([id$=saveFormPanel])"
    oncomplete="validateDataStructure('one')"/>


<script>
function validateDataStructure(count){
console.log(count);
}
</script>
```

but I got an error like this
**Error: Uncaught reference error: count is not defined**

can anyone help to fix this issue.